# export Report in Excel using Bi publisher

Tags: excel, bi-publisher

I have two Layout in my Report(Report 1)

Under Report1 i have layout 1 and Layout 2

if i use Export to Excel option in Bi publisher then i am getting only layout 1 or layout 2 in excel.

I want the Report1 to be export in Excel file named as 'Report1.xlsx' and having two worksheet one with name 'Layout1' and next with 'Layout2'

Note:Report is an on demand report .it should be View in online then export in Excel .please provide an workaround to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to add all the content in one layout and use  Page Breaks to split the content. Then go to the report Properties and set the option Page Break as New Sheet  to  True . This will break the content in some sheets in excel depending on the number of page breaks you use. The downside is that when in Interactive view all the content will be in the same page.
Hope it helps!